# how to create turns using while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm struggling to create a turn using while loop in python

```
import random

x=[]
y=[]

playerturn = 0

while playerturn == 0:
    randx = random.randint(1,5)
    randy = random.randint(1,5)
    
    x.append(randx)
    y.append(randy)

    playerturn = 1
    
while playerturn == 1:
    if x > y :
        print("X wins")
        playerturn = 0
        
    if x == y:
        print("draw")
        playerturn = 2
        
    if x < y:
        print("Y wins")
        playerturn = 0
        
while playerturn == 2:
    break
```

If I run the code, instead of running the program until x and y are equal, it will stop after the first run. How can I alter the code where it will generate a number and add to the list until x and y are equal?

Comment: why are you comparing 2 lists? What result do you expect when you compare, for example, `[1, 2, 3] > [2, 1, 5]` ? Is there even a reason to have those lists? What exactly should your game be doing - explain in english please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have confused the control flow of structured programming. Before I explain how you should do this, I will explain what you did *wrong*.

To understand that, you need to know what your code does. First realize that, your code runs from top to bottom.

```py
x=[]
y=[]

playerturn = 0
```

Creates `x` and `y` list, and creates a variable called `playerturn` and sets it to 0

```py
while playerturn == 0:
    randx = random.randint(1,5)
    randy = random.randint(1,5)
    
    x.append(randx)
    y.append(randy)

    playerturn = 1
```

This *only runs once*. Because at the end of the loop (`playerturn = 1`), `playerturn` becomes 1. So it immediately **breaks out of the loop**.

Once this loop has been broken out of, your code *will never go inside it again*. The reason is simple - Code runs from top to bottom.

See the problem? In your final loop, you try to set `playerturn` to a specific value according to the conditions. Now *you're expecting the **first and second loops** to start again* according to these values. But how can they? Those lines have already been passed and they're never called again.

Thus, your program exits. As it has reached the end of the program.

I think you wanted to put all those conditions *inside one loop*. I don't really see why you're trying to use 3 loops. All those loops are completely separate from each other.

From what I can tell, what you're trying to do - this is what I can come up with.

```py
while True:
    randx = random.randint(1,5)
    randy = random.randint(1,5)
    
    if randx > randy:
        print("X wins")
    elif randx < randy:
        print("Y wins")
    else:
        print("Draw")
        break
```

This will run and print "X wins" or "Y wins" until there's a "Draw", in which case, it'll `break` and stop.

There's no reason to maintain `playerturn`, since it resets to known values in known logical conditions.

There's no reason to maintain the lists `x` and `y`, because comparison between lists is often not something you want to do, unless it's just equality.

Now to explain, how this code works-

- `while True:` - infinite loop
- ```py
  randx = random.randint(1,5)
  randy = random.randint(1,5)
  ```

  Choose a random integer between `1` and `5` and assign them to `randx` and `randy`
- ```py
  if randx > randy:
      print("X wins")
  elif randx < randy:
      print("Y wins")
  else:
      print("Draw")
      break
  ```

  If `randx` is greater than `randy`, print `"X wins"` and vice versa.

  If they're equal, print `"Draw"` and break out of loop.

  Since the loop is the only thing in the program. After breaking out, the program will stop.

Possible Output (this is randomized)-

> Y wins
>
> Y wins
>
> X wins
>
> X wins
>
> Draw

Comment: wow thank you so much for your detailed answer! I am new to python(just started last week) and started working on a blackjack project and my idea was to create turns for each players/dealers. I was afraid that the full code was too long so I made a summary of what I was trying to do and this definitely helps! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `while True`:

```
import random

x=[]
y=[]

playerturn = 0

while True:

    if playerturn == 0:
        randx = random.randint(1,5)
        randy = random.randint(1,5)
        
        x.append(randx)
        y.append(randy)
    
        playerturn = 1
        
    if playerturn == 1:
        if x[-1] > y[-1] :
            print("X wins")
            playerturn = 0
            
        if x[-1] == y[-1]:
            print("draw")
            playerturn = 2
            
        if x[-1] < y[-1]:
            print("Y wins")
            playerturn = 0
            
    if playerturn == 2:
        break
```

Comment: have you checked this? the x and y are arrays

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get whats your game really is. but if u have to run your code  until you get last x entry and y entry are equal. u can try the below code

```
import random

x = []
y = []

playerturn = 0

while playerturn == 0:
    randx = random.randint(1, 5)
    randy = random.randint(1, 5)

    x.append(randx)
    y.append(randy)

    playerturn = 1

    while playerturn == 1:
        if x[-1] > y[-1]:
            print("X wins")
            playerturn = 0

        if x[-1] == y[-1]:
            print("draw")
            playerturn = 2

        if x[-1] < y[-1]:
            print("Y wins")
            playerturn = 0

    while playerturn == 2:
        break
```

which will give you an output like

```
X wins
Y wins
X wins
Y wins
X wins
X wins
X wins
Y wins
draw
```